# How to disable align-wide for specified blocks in Gutenberg

Tags: block-editor

I added support for `align-wide` to my theme, but I don't know how to disable this feature for some existing blocks.

I check [Gutenberg documentation](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/) but I can't find solution.

```
add_theme_support( 'align-wide' );
```

Answer (score 7):

According to [the gutenberg handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-registration/#registerblocktype) you can use the `blocks.registerBlockType` filter which allows you to play around with the block settings.

For most of the wp core blocks modifying the `supports.align` property works pretty well:

```js
wp.hooks.addFilter(
    'blocks.registerBlockType',
    'my-theme/namespace',
    function( settings, name ) {
        if ( name === 'core/pullquote' ) {
            return lodash.assign( {}, settings, {
                supports: lodash.assign( {}, settings.supports, {
                    // disable the align-UI completely ...
                    align: false, 
                    // ... or only allow specific alignments
                    // align: ['center,'full'], 
                } ),
            } );
        }
        return settings;
    }
);
```

In my tests this worked for most of wp core blocks, except for `core/image`, `core/paragraph`, `core/heading` and `core/quote`.

### Troublesome Image Block

As for WP 5.0.3 (and at least up to 5.3) these blocks will receive an additional alignment control like this:

[image: Additional Alignments]

with code:

```js
        ...
        {
            align: ['left','full'], 
        }
        ...
```

To control the available alignments for the `core/image` block, you would have to modify the edit method of a block using the [`editor.BlockEdit`](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/filters/block-filters/#editor-blockedit) filter.

### Nasty Headings, Paragraphs & Quotes

The problem with `core/paragraph`, `core/heading` and `core/quote` is, that block-align (defined by classenames `alignleft`, `alignwide`, ... in the frontend and the `data-align` attribute in the editor) is not clearly separated from the text-align (defined in the style attribute), which leads to odd results like this:
[image: Odd core/paragraph]

**[UPDATE 2019-11-13]:** As of WP 5.3 this works pretty well with `core/cover` now.

Comment: There is an issue on `core/image` and `core/cover` blocks now: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/13780

Answer (score 2):

Are you referring to blocks you've built yourself or existing blocks?

If you are building your own blocks you can do something like this:

`<BlockControls key="controls">
    <BlockAlignmentToolbar
        value={ align }
        onChange={ ( align ) => setAttributes( { align } ) }
        controls={ [ 'wide', 'full' ] }
    />
</BlockControls>`

Make sure you include the components:

`const { BlockControls, BlockAlignmentToolbar } = wp.editor;`

If you are looking to limit the Alignment of existing blocks, then I'm not sure if that is possible at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I must disable alignment of some existing blocks. Sorry, my mistake. I did not write this.

Comment: You could overwrite the CSS for just those blocks? For example:

```.wp-block-cover-image.alignwide {
     /* your custom CSS here */
}```

Comment: This is good method but when the design is still this same then the options (align-wide, align-full) are unnecessary.

Comment: I was looking for a solution to remove a custom "BlockAlignmentToolbar" (just like you posted it here), which was not added via the "supports" attribute. So far I wasn't able to find any solution. So @DannyCooper 's solution seems to be the best fit for me at this point.